# Is it a problem if site and domain name includes "hub"

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

My site and domain name includes the word part "hub". This was the main reason why my site get rejected firstly for "Google News" because it was connected with sexual content (which it doesn't include of course).
I got a screenshot from google with my page and the "hub" in my site logo was marked. After I've complained they have listed my site now on "Google News." Apparently the word part "hub" gets connected with a big adult site by google.

Are there any more problems regarding my site name in terms of indexing or SEO ranking? Should I change my site and domain name to prevent any disadvantages in the future which would mean to choose a name without including "hub" in it?

Comment: I'm surprised Google would say that "Hub" means "porn".  There are a couple porn sites that use it in their name, but there are plenty of non-porn uses.  For example HubSpot is a pretty big site that isn't porn-centric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the word "hub" in your domain should not be an issue.

I guess a human moderator made a wrong decision and associated the word hub with adult sites. The fact that they changed their mind after you complained shows, that it was not intentional.